# Is there any limit on number of Listeners(subscription client) of a Subscription created under a topic in Azure Service Bus(pub-sub)?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, publish-subscribe

I am looking on using Azure Service Bus topic to publish some messages to my service. I have creted a subscription for my service and have got connection string.
My service(WebApi) is running on large number of instances (1000s). I am thinking of starting the listeners of Azure Service Bus at app start of my service using connection string in all the instances. Are there any issues in running large number of listeners(my service instances) under one Azure Service Bus subscription. I am fine with only one instance receiving the message(This is infact what I prefer).

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout all limits wrt Azure Service Bus from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas

Comment: The link doesn't explicitly say about any limit on  number of listeners that can be created using subscription client of per topic per subscription. I basically want to understand is it fine to have  listeners in all my service instances or not?

Comment: i honestly thought it would have something useful for you but if not then you can ask this question to azure support from azure portal directly. top right corner with a question mark, i have not run into this as of yet.

Comment: Thanks Hassan. Have asked azure support